# Filter PHP Table created by while loop

Tags: javascript, php, html, search, filter

Hey I have a HTML table which is created by a PHP while loop. For this I would like to have an input which can search the table. The normal JavaScript version I found on the internet doesn't work. I think it's because the table is not in the HTML source code, but inserted by PHP. Thank you for any answer and have a nice day!

```
<table class="table" id="searchtable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Username</th>
      <th scope="col">Rank</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php
    require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/req/config.php';
    $stmt = $sql->prepare("SELECT * FROM users");
    $stmt->execute();
    while ($result = $stmt->fetch()) {
      ?>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row"><?php echo $result["username"] ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $result["rank"] ?></th>
      </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Your desired search and filter should done by SQL statements, `$stmt = $sql->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE \`username\`='bob'");`

Comment: what do you exactly need for this question? do you need to  just get the rows or you need to get the whole table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not difference for the browser whether table was created by PHP or manually. You could simply use wrongly the "javascript version" you found. You can carefully try to implement this [example of code](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_table.asp)